# ¿Cómo solucionar un problemas al migrar un proyecto local a un host?

Tags: php, web, localhost, host

soy nuevo en este tipo de temas y tengo problemas al pasar mi proyecto local realizado en html, css, javascript y php hecho de manera local con una distribución de xampp pero al momento de subir el proyecto al host que en este caso es hostinger en una carpeta creada sobre un proyecto de WordPress y ligada con un botón para ejecutar el index de min proyecto tengo problemas con algunas url de paginas que están presentes en su navegación, también al formar algunos archivos json de un crud. Tomando en cuenta que de manera local no tengo estos problemas y actualmente está dado de alta en el servidor una versión del proyecto que no tiene este inconveniente pero al incluir el crud me generó dicho dilema.

Las versiones de php son distintas del local y el host y como mencione esta dentro de un proyecto de WordPress y se que se genero actualmente este problema porque ya había logrado subir una primera versión del proyecto. Estoy por actualizar la versión de php del servidor pero estoy generando respaldos de todo lo que tengo almacenado para evitar problemas, en cuanto depurar el código linea por linea no se desde donde partir ¿Algún consejo que me puedan brindar?

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Comment: ¿Qué versiones de PHP?. ¿Revisaste los logs?. ¿Localmente lo probaste junto con WP?.

Comment: Si hice la prueba de manera local en un proyecto de WP, la versión php del host era 8.0 y el local 8.2 y revisar los logs escapa de mi conocimiento actual. Al actualizar el php del host continuo con el problema. cabe mencionar que para el crud estoy ocupando ajax, jquery y boostrap en su forma común de Data Table.